# Can some one explain me the following Java snippet for recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, stack

```java
public class GetElementWithoutPop {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.push(10);
        stack.push(20);
        stack.push(30);
        stack.push(40);
        stack.push(50);
        stack.push(60);
        System.out.println("value is: " + GetElementWithoutPop.getStackElement(stack, 3));
        System.out.println("stack is " + stack);

        // Using Java
        int position = 3;
        Integer result = stack.get(position);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public static <T> T getStackElement(Stack<T> stack, int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return stack.peek();
        }

        T x = stack.pop();
        try {

            return getStackElement(stack, index - 1);
        } finally {
            stack.push(x);
        }
    }

}
```

Till the index becomes 0 from 3 it's all good and simple, but after that the code goes back to `try` block and then again to `finally` block and the index starts to increase on its own all the way back to 3 and `stack.push(x)` brings the stack back to its original state.

How is this happening?
Fairly new to recursions & I need to understand this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because each function call has its own unique context for the same function so the variable x stores the popped variable and calls recursively to pop further value but that value is stored in x of  the next function call, while returning the finally block runs and each unique value of x in each function call is again pushed

```
T x = stack.pop();           // this value remains stored in the function call stack
    try {

        return getStackElement(stack, index - 1);  // same function runs for further case (n-1) th and stores the value in its own x variable in its context
    } finally {
        stack.push(x);      // after the control returns, this copy of function has its  unique x variable and that is pushed again
    }
```

You mention that "index starts to increase on its own all the way back to 3 .." that's because each function call has its own set of variables including index

Some Steps

1) Function call instance with index 3 calls function with index 2

2) Function call instance with index 2 calls function with index 1

3) Function call instance with index 1 calls function with index 0

4) Control returns

5) Now the control is back to instance with index value 1

6) Control returns from even that instance and now is back to instance with index 2

This is like winding and then unwinding,, while solving problems with recursion we have to often decide whether we want to do some work at call for n and then call for n-1 OR call for n-1 , let the control return and then do some work